# Unity I am trying to make a bool to trigger walking and running animations but they overlap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I am working on a script that if the user presses shift and W the sprint animation will play or if the just press W they will walk. The problem is it always goes to walk.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Sprint", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: just debug your code - then rewrite your if statements

Comment: @vasily.sib I have been doing that all day.

Comment: ok, then lets start verbal debugging session. What happens when you press only `W` key? I mean what is the result of `(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)`, `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)` and `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)`?

Comment: @vasily.sib I actually got it fixed right after I commented.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code to successfully switch between walk ad run animations.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", true);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Sprint", true);
            anim.SetBool("Walk", false);

        }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
        anim.SetBool("Sprint", false);
        anim.SetBool("IdleToSprint", false);


        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            anim.SetBool("SprintToWalk", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would post a screenshot of your animations controller tree it would be easier to answe this. But judging from how you set your variables I'm guessing you have an idle animation and then out of it two branches that are walk and sprint.

Based off of that assumption I can suggest that you change your script like this:

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
    anim.SetBool("Sprint", false);
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Sprint", true);
        anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. If you have the anim controller set up a different way OR if it still doesent work please edit the question with a screenshot of that animation controller.

Comment: it did not work. if I try to sprint it will sprint then immediately go to idle and walk.

Comment: Oh okay, I did not realize you have a walk to sprint animation in between. Can you tell me what you have for conditions on all transitions?

Comment: You actually got me started though. I will post my code as an answer